# Ajax file upload progress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Well, I am trying to implement file upload with Ajax and Php in my local apache server.

**strong text**

```
     $('.uploadButton').click(function(){
                    var formData = new FormData($(this).closest('.fileUploadForm'));
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'upload.php',  //Server script to process data
                        type: 'POST',
                        xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                            if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                                myXhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                                    $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
                                    $(".progress-bar span").css('width',e.loaded);
                                };
                            }
                            return myXhr;
                        },
                        error: function(xhr,status,error)
                        {
                            //$('.progressBarDiv progress').hide();
                            console.log('Error '+xhr+"  "+status+"  "+error);
                        },
                        data: formData,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    });
```

**PHP CODE**

```
  <?php

    $folder = "upload/";
    $path = $folder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    } else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
   ?>
```

**Error**

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file in <b>C:\Users\gopir\Server\Apache24\ 
\htdocs\front-page\upload.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br /><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file in <b>C:\Users\gopir\Server\Apache24 
\htdocs\front-page\upload.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
 There was an error uploading the file, please try again!   success
```

**Line that caused error is:**

```
  var formData = new FormData($(this).closest('.fileUploadForm'));
```

If i change this line to

```
 var formData = new FormData($('form')[0])
```

program works fine.

I can able to see the form data in the console by setting breakpoints in my js. 
I don't know how to solve this.

I am changing this to achieve multiple file upload functionality.

Please let me know how do i solve this issue. Thanks

**HTML**

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="fileUploadForm" >
        <div class="uploadDiv"> 
            </div>
            <div class="progressUploadDiv">     
                <div class="uploadButton">Upload</div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: The error you are having is on line 4 of `upload.php`, so that would be: `$path = $folder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);`  I would `print_r` your `$_FILES`.  I bet that is empty for some reason.

Comment: I would also `print_r` your `$_POST` and `$_GET` because you're telling jQuery to post data... some of the examples like this make it seem like the some jQuery black magic or something though...

Comment: @xbakesx Yes it's empty. How is it possible. it prints complete Array()

Comment: @xbakesx All array returns no values. How is it so

Comment: can you console.log(formData); ??

Comment: Yes I can. Probelm is data is not posting.

Comment: That can't be all your html... where is your the part where you select a file to upload?  There has to be something like `<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">` on there, right?

Comment: Yes Yes. i deleted it for simplicity. I ll add that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormData constructor parameter is HTML `<form>` element. Try code below.

```
var formData = new FormData($(this).closest('.fileUploadForm')[0]);
```

> When creating new elements (or selecting existing ones), jQuery returns the elements in a collection. Many developers new to jQuery assume that this collection is an array. It has a zero-indexed sequence of DOM elements, some familiar array functions, and a .length property, after all. Actually, the jQuery object is more complicated than that.

Source: [The jQuery Object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)

Comment: Why did you add 2 answers. Isn't my code posts html elment?

Comment: It was meant to be edit, but some server glitch happened I guess.

Comment: ok.Please tell me what `$('.selector').closest('.class')` returns? Isn't a html element?

Comment: Updated my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Multiupload file just it not

> $_FILES['file']['name']

It mush be

> $_FILES['files']['name']

example for access multifile uploaded to server

```
$fileSelected = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
$_temp = 0;
foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
     $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
     if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $folder)){
          //Upload successful
     }else{
          //Fail
     }
}
```

I hope this help

Comment: No No No. I am trying it differently. I am trying to multiply my upload button and input type file. So that each upload button upload corresponding file